# Filtering table record based on time availability in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have one table `tblAvailability` in which I have two column `StartTime time` and `EndTime time`.

There I set `StartTime=7 AM` and `EndTime=10`.
Now I have filter in front end which send time range like `6 TO 10 OR 7:30 TO 10` like this.

I wrote the SQL query like below.

```
Where  CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 108) >= CONVERT(varchar, @startTime, 108)
AND CONVERT(varchar, EndTime, 108) <= CONVERT(varchar, @endTime, 108)
```

Now I would like to filter out rows based on start and end time range, means would like to get all records table whose start and end time ranges between selected time range.

Comment: Why are you converting your times to a `varchar` here?

Comment: are `StartTime` and `EndTime` not datatype `DATETIME` ?

Comment: those are datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, you are not clear whether you are using time of date or date and time. Can you please post more information.

You should be aware that date types and ranges in SQL Server can differ to a client language such as C# (although you don't mention your client language). For example, if you are using SQL Server "datetime" you can restrict the client date range in C# by using the appropriate type, e.g.

```
System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime
```

You say you have written a query you want to use as to filter some data, which I assume you run within SQL Server.

Assume using C# as the client, an efficient way of returning data is to write a View in SQL Server and add this to an Entity Framework model. To query this data at the client, use LinqSQL which will convert your client code into SQL and runs surprisingly efficiently.

```
var filteredData = (from i in _db.vw_SomeData where i.StartDate >= fromDate && i.EndDate < toDate select i).ToList()
```

Be careful of your data endpoints (inclusive and exclusive values). If you use SQL Server datetime and you want all times within a day, then I use (date >= today and date < tomorrow) which is guaranteed to work. trying to test against the last second of the day with a "less than or equals" won't work where there is a time between the last second and midnight.

To sum up, comparing date and or time is best performed natively for those types. Only where some of the comparison data is a string should you convert one to the other. The only easily sortable and comparable date and time is yyyymmdd and HHmmss

Comment: Thanks @pixelda but I am going to query it in Sql Server so above might not be useful for me.Thanks once again.
I need to filter records between provided start and end time range.

Comment: Dates in SQL Server are always stored in a particular way but can be displayed differently depending on how your server setup. I suggest comparing dates natively rather than converting to some other type. Remember to decide how the ends of the range will be compared - whether the lower end should be greater than or greater than or equal to for example. If I have to set a date manually I like to use medium format because it is clear. e.g. set @mydate = '01-Jun-2018 13:12:12'